# How can I extend template with custom javascript for modal window in the Sonata Admin (Symfony 3.3, PHP 7)?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have an entity structure:

```
Deal -->       DealCondition <-- Product
id             id                id
dealConditons  product           name
```

I have the admin sections:

DealAdmin:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->add('dealConditions', 
        'sonata_type_collection',
        [
            'by_reference' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ],
        [
            'edit'     => 'inline',
            'inline'   => 'table',
            'sortable' => 'position',
        ]);
...}
```

ProductConditionAdmin:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->add('product','sonata_type_model');
}
```

ProductAdmin:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->add('name', null);
}
```

On ProductAdmin page I need some javascript to my purposes, so I did this:

```
    application.admin.product:
    class: ...\ProductAdmin
    tags:
      - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label_translator_strategy: "sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore"}
    arguments:
      - ~
      - ...\Product
      - ~
    calls:
      - [setTemplates, [{
        edit: ApplicationDealBundle:ProductAdmin:edit.html.twig}]]
```

And in edit.html.twig:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}<script type="text/javascript">MyScript();</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Everything works when I open ProductAdmin as main page, but when I click "Add new product" button next to Product field on nested form DealConditions, the script doesn't exist. 
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUvJV.jpg)

How can I add the script?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may have resolved this issue by now, but I had the same problematic yesterday so I'll put how I've done if others come here.

There may be better / more elegant solutions but this works just fine for now. What I've done is to override the base `edit_many_script.html.twig` which `manages the many-to-[one|many] association field popup`

Copy paste the file from  `vendor` and put it in your `app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/CRUD/Association` directory (or create it).

You'll find inside the file this ajax call to retrieve the admin form for your entity :

```
// retrieve the form element from the related admin generator
jQuery.ajax({
    url: a.attr('href'),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
         Admin.log('[{{ id }}|field_dialog_form_edit] ajax success', field_dialog_{{ id }});
         // populate the popup container
         field_dialog_content_{{ id }}.html(html);
         field_dialog_title_{{ id }}.html("{{ associationadmin.label|trans({}, associationadmin.translationdomain) }}");

         Admin.shared_setup(field_dialog_{{ id }});

         // capture the submit event to make an ajax call, ie : POST data to the
         // related create admin
         jQuery(document).on('click','#field_dialog_{{ id }} a', field_dialog_form_action_{{ id }});
         jQuery('form', field_dialog_{{ id }}).on('submit', field_dialog_form_action_{{ id }});

         // open the dialog in modal mode
         field_dialog_{{ id }}.modal();

         Admin.setup_list_modal(field_dialog_{{ id }});
    }
});
```

You can add your script there. Note that it will be used by default for every many to X relations, so if you want your script to be loaded only in specific situations, you can test `{{ associationadmin.label|trans({}, associationadmin.translationdomain) }}` like the following:

```
// retrieve the form element from the related admin generator
jQuery.ajax({
    url: a.attr('href'),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
         Admin.log('[{{ id }}|field_dialog_form_edit] ajax success', field_dialog_{{ id }});
         // populate the popup container
         field_dialog_content_{{ id }}.html(html);
         field_dialog_title_{{ id }}.html("{{ associationadmin.label|trans({}, associationadmin.translationdomain) }}");

         Admin.shared_setup(field_dialog_{{ id }});

         // capture the submit event to make an ajax call, ie : POST data to the
         // related create admin
         jQuery(document).on('click','#field_dialog_{{ id }} a', field_dialog_form_action_{{ id }});
         jQuery('form', field_dialog_{{ id }}).on('submit', field_dialog_form_action_{{ id }});

         // Custom JS for PopUpWidget Entity
         if("{{ associationadmin.label|trans({}, associationadmin.translationdomain) }}" === "PopUpWidget"){
             //your script
         }

         // open the dialog in modal mode
         field_dialog_{{ id }}.modal();

         Admin.setup_list_modal(field_dialog_{{ id }});
    }
});
```